# Loading images in listview from remote location

Tags: android, android-listview, uiimageview

This might seems to be repeated question, but could not get best answer

what is the best method to load images in listview?

AsyncTask or Android Universal Image Loader or Robospice UI Spice List?

Can any one explain me the advantages and disvantages?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use GLide Image Loader

Glide is a fast and efficient open source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and disk caching, and resource pooling into a simple and easy to use interface.

```
https://github.com/bumptech/glide
```

You can use Picasso also

```
https://github.com/square/picasso
```

You can compare GLide and Picasso

```
http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en
```